# What is the meaning of <> in Promise<string>?

Tags: typescript

What is the meaning of `<>` in `Promise<string>`?

Example:

```
export interface ReviewModel extends mongoose.Model<ReviewDocument> {
  generateToken(): Promise<string>
}
```

Comment: Look up "generics". It basically it says the function returns a promise that ultimately results in a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angle brackets (`<>`) come into play when we are discussing **[generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)** in TypeScript.

In this case, we are saying that `generateToken()` will return a `Promise` that resolves to a `string` value, meaning we can use the function like so:

```
generateToken().then((value) => console.log(value)); // value is type 'string'
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<>` notation is common across programming languages to denote a generic assignment. In the case of `Promise<string>`, you are denoting that the thing returned will be a `Promise` object, whose implementation will all be referencing the `string` type.

```
generateToken(): Promise<string>;
connect(): Promise<void>;
fetchDate(): Promise<Date>;

...
await token: string = model.generateToken();
await model.connect();
await now: Date = model.fetchDate();

model.generateToken().then((token: string) => console.log(`got ${token}`));
model.connect().then(() => console.log('connected!'));
model.fetchDate().then((date: Date) => console.log(`reported date: ${date}`));
```